# how to pass arguments from a .bat file (without reading .bat file contents) to python .py file

Tags: python

test.bat file has below line

python test.py arg1 arg2

On running test.bat in cmd, file will be executed automatically, so without reading the lines of test.bat, I want to execute test.py by passing arg1 & arg2, which will be used by .py file. When I execute above test.bat im cmd, it runs test.py but not taking arg1 & arg2 as its arguments. How can it be done without actually reading the line contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sys.argv to get arguments passed from the command line/ bat file to your Python program, like this:

```
import sys

print ('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))
```

Comment: @rajgary You can name the file "test" (with no extension) instead of test.py.